"What God can't do doesn't exist"
Is this a right saying, what God can’t do doesn’t exist?
It has come to my attention that this is one of the most popular sayings amongst Christians nowadays. But I think it’s somewhat a problematic or ambiguous phrase.
For example sin exists however  God does not commit sin.

I've never heard that, but you're correct.  It is nonsensical.  Similar to "let go and let God".  God is not operating the way so many believe that He is in this age where His "grace is sufficient" (2 Cor 12:9).

My answer has two verses.  To keep your question from being closed, you need to ask your question based on one of these.

Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 17,000 question/answer contributions as to the way these policies play out in practice. Moderators are elected by the Community of users to maintain the integrity of the site. Welcome to SE-BH. (Questions which do not directly relate to the text of scripture may be voted to closure as being off-topic.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Obviously lies and temptation exists.  When you look at what God cannot do:

... it is impossible for God to lie, ...
(Heb. 6:18, ESV)


Let no one say when he is tempted, “I am being tempted by God,” for God cannot be tempted with evil, and he himself tempts no one.
(James 1:13, ESV)

It is not that God does not have the strength or physical ability to do it, but that his chosen attributes exclude him from doing it.
Part of what make this difficult to understand is understanding time.  Physics tells us that time is not independent of matter.  Thus, when God created matter, he created time.  Thus, God established his attributes before time.

You have not supported the concept of God 'establishing his attributes' with scripture. What God himself said is 'I am that I am'. Eternally He is. Your expression  'before time' is a contradiction in terms.

I do not know what this was downvoted but my upvote will help balance things out.  Good answer.

The statement "What God cannot do doesn't exist" is associated with Streams of Joy International Ministry (SOJ), led by Pastor Jerry Eze. This ministry, founded in 2008 in Umuahia, Abia State Nigeria, actively promotes this statement to inspire faith and emphasize God's omnipotence.
To answer your question, the statement may be popular among Christians who actively participate in their YouTube channel. However, compared to the larger evangelistic church community, SOJ remains relatively small. Thus, the claim that this statement is popular among all Christians might be exaggerated.
The statement, if intended to emphasize God's omnipotence, is problematic and ambiguous. While SOJ may have their interpretation, it remains unique to them and those who accept it, unless it receives general acceptance within the broader Christian community.
God's omnipotence encompasses His unlimited power and sovereignty, but it must be consistent with His nature. This means He will not act in a way that contradicts His own nature, such as committing acts of unrighteousness or sin.
The statement may reflect the sentiment in Matthew 19:26, which states, "With God all things are possible". Without proper understanding, one might mistakenly interpret this to mean that even evil is created by God. However, evil is a by-product of the free will given to humanity. God created humans as living beings with free will (Genesis 2:7), not as programmed robots.
